# SVG container element that doesn't auto-scale according to children

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to implement a tooltip. The idea in its most simplicity is to show a rectangular, when hovered on a circle. How can I achieve that?

What I do not want is to show the rectangular when not hovered precisely on the circle.

Please check the example: https://codepen.io/EminDurak/pen/JXOVqv

SVG:

```
<svg width="800px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 800 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<g x="282.7416666666667" y="252.6" width="3" height="3" class="tooltip-container">

  <circle cx="200" cy="120" r="20" value="12" class="tooltip-circle"></circle>

  <rect x="50" y="30" width="300" height="80" rx="4" ry="4" r="5" value="12" class="tooltip-box"></rect>

  <text x="100" y="80" style="fill:black">Shouldn't appear when hovered here</text>
  <text  x="150" y="160" style="fill:black">Hover the circle</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

And the CSS (SCSS):

```
.tooltip-box {
  fill: purple;
  opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.tooltip-container {
  &:hover > * {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: You want the hover pseudo class to be attached to the circle and not the g then.

Comment: Of course that was the first thing I tried. Doesn't work...

Comment: Show me what you tried so I can correct it then.

Comment: Thanks. Simply, putting the <rect> element inside the <circle>. Then it doesn't show anything... Have you checked the codepen link I attached??

Comment: You can't do that, you need to fix the CSS so that it only applies the hover to the circle as I said in my first comment.

Comment: Yes, of course that I also fixed :) Check the codepen again: https://codepen.io/EminDurak/pen/JXOVqv

Comment: And I said about the rect in circle idea that "you can't do that"

Comment: Can you pls post a link to a working example? It's not easy to follow here... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the best solution to this problem is using `display:none`, instead of `opacity:0`. At the time of writing the question I had not checked which css selectors work for SVG; didn't think display would be one. But it is.

So this code below works:

```
<g x="282.7416666666667" y="252.6" width="3" height="3" class="tooltip-container">

  <circle cx="200" cy="120" r="20" value="12" class="tooltip-circle"></circle>

  <rect x="50" y="30" width="300" height="80" rx="4" ry="4" r="5" value="12" class="tooltip-box"></rect>

</g>
```

and css:

```
.tooltip-box {
  fill: purple;
  opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.tooltip-container:hover > .tooltip-box {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Note: The reason I placed the `<Text>` element was just to indicate what I was trying to do. The main point is that when an svg element is set to `display:none`, the container `<g>` element's size is computed accordingly, so as if the svg element is not rendered at all. Then one can set the element to `display: block` on hovered to container `<g>` and consequentially be able to exercise, let's say, a tooltip function.